# Emacs: how to load an ansi-term buffer at startup?

Tags: emacs, ansi-term

I have figured how to close the *scratch* buffer and the *GNU Emacs* buffer, and I would now like to have a terminal started automatically within emacs, instead of having to type manually `M-x ansi-term`. I saw a couple posts explaining how to load a file at startup, but I believe the ansi-term buffer is a bit different.

I'd rather modify my .emacs than create an alias for emacs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook
  (lambda ()
    (kill-buffer "*scratch*")
    (ansi-term "/bin/bash")
  ))
```